# Loadash is not validating string Negative values in javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working on React Native project. And I am getting response from server, And the response is like below.

```
        {
        "id": 12,
        "year": 2019,
        "percentage": "-0.45",
    }, {
        "id": 13,
        "year": 2018,
        "percentage": "4.45",
    },
```

So, I have to check either empty or not particular field, If it is empty, I have to set **0** to that label in UI.

For that I am using Loadash library for validation checking.

```
 value: !isEmpty(get(item, 'percentage').replace('-', '').replace(/[,-]/g, '') ? get(item, 'percentage') : '0')
```

But, Its not validating negative values inside string.
Any suggestions?

Comment: `'Percentage'` not `'percentage'` (capital P)

Comment: Its my mistake, I have edited the field, but, I have updated field, But, Still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You close the parenthesis at the very end. It's the wrong place. Put it here, just before the `?` :

```
value: !isEmpty(get(item, 'percentage').replace('-', '').replace(/[,-]/g, '')) ? get(item, 'percentage') : '0'
```

Long lines are always hard to read and debug, so try to break down the code.

```
let percentage = get(item, 'percentage'),
    p = percentage.replace(/[,-]/g, '');

value : !isEmpty(p) ? p : 0;
```

Had you done that, you would have noticed your mistake which is :

```
 value : !isEmpty(p ? p : 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is case-sensitive. So change `percentage` to `Percentage`:

```
value: !isEmpty(get(item, 'Percentage').replace('-', '').replace(/[,-]/g, '') ? 
    get(item, 'Percentage') : '0')
```

Comment: Its my mistake, I have edited the field, but, I have updated field, But, Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

there are either two ways to do that, (1st may not work in React Native)
Keep the default value for your tags as 0, so whenever you receive some empty string in the dom or in your JSON itself, it will handle the problem. As I said, React doesnt support it I guess.

2nd. 
Check before binding in the front end. 
a. check whether your value for individual keys are empty or NA or undefined and then set it as 0 (as you need it). For an instance, if its empty then use the bind function to set as 0 OR set the variable using this function. This is a trivial way to do it.

Use _.get in ES6

The advantage of _.get is, you omit continuing checks if a property exist, which would be necessary.

Hope this helps.